I am looking for a simple function that is smooth, periodic each period has a clearly distinguished peak
Assume a product is sold often every July but sold very little outside of that and I have data about when it sells and how many. I want to fit a periodic curve that captures this trend. Of course, I could come up with some function expressed as a sort of Fourier-series or something like that, but that requires relatively a lot of parameters to be estimated, which I don't like. So I would like to have a simple function that does a bump in July (but is periodic) and otherwise is more or less flat and I want to have this curve to have as few degrees of freedom as possible (I imagine 3 should be enough - the phase where it peaks, the size of the peak and how spread-out it is). I want this function not only periodic, but also smoothly continuous. An obvious non-smooth choice would be some sort of triangle, but I want a smooth one. Any ideas?

If you just want a rough estimate you could compute average sales for each date and fit a scaled Gaussian?

@StevenGubkin, this would make a fine answer. (Another alternative would be a sinusoidal curve, appropriately scaled, raised to a power.)

Based on comments by @Steven Gubkin I came up with a function that has the specified properties:
$$f(t) = a \left(\left(\exp(\sin(t - \phi) - 1)\right)^\sigma\right)$$

Just want to note that it is considered a good practice by the community to accept your own answer if you find a solution.

I found out later that this is apparently this is related to the von Mises distribution and others can be found among the circular distributions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_distribution

Here is one idea if you just want a rough estimate:

First compute the average sales data for each date.
Fit a scaled Gaussian to this data.

This has three parameters to fit:
$$
\theta_1 \exp\left(-\frac{(x - \theta_2)^2}{\theta_3}\right)
$$
Use this to predict sales for any given date.

The OP wanted a periodic function, which repeats year after year. How does this Gaussian become periodic? At a minimum it needs a modulo operator (e.g. modulo 12 if $x$ is in months, 52 if $x$ is in weeks...)

@jginestet I would think that it is obvious how to apply the model periodically:  if you want to predict sales on July 20th of any year then plug in that date into the fitted model.  This is equivalent to your "modulo" suggestion.  There is a bit of a hick up here with leap years, but I am just suggesting a starting point.

It's not obvious, how to make it periodic. If you do this, you get a point of discontinuity or at least non-smoothness wherever one year ends and another year begins. I mean you could perhaps fix this by copying it for each year and then summing it over all integers? But that feels kinda computationally heavy. Was hoping for something simpler.

@user1747134 It will be a non-differentiable point, but for your use-case it should be virtually indistinguishable from 0 near the end points.  The standard deviation will probably be on the order of 15 days, so half a year is roughly 10 sigma (aka zero).

@user1747134 Feel free to use Ben Bolker's suggestion instead if you want it to be truly smooth and periodic!  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y2aurmb4sf

I like the scaled cos solution, but I wonder if it's possible to modify so that the parameter k is real-valued. That doesn't seem straightforward, as that starts behaving weirdly if the exponent is odd or non-integer.

@user1747134 You could just write is as $\left(\sin^2(\textrm{blah})\right)^k$. Then $k$ can take on real values greater than or equal to 1 without issue.  I made that change to the Desmos link.
